# Error: "Can't set headers after they are sent."

Tags: node.js, express, connect-flash

I'm new to nodejs and its routes system. I'm getting "Can't set headers after they are sent." only on production mode only on Heroku (It works fine locally).

// Login =========================================

```
router.get('/', ifLoggedOut, function(req, res, next){
    res.render('login', { message: req.flash('message')});
});

router.post('/login', function(req, res, next){
    var username = req.body.username;
    var password = req.body.password;

    req.checkBody('username', 'Username field is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('username', 'Password field is required').notEmpty();

    req.checkBody('password', 'Invalid Credintials').len(8, 20);
    req.checkBody('username', 'Invalid Credintials').len(4, 20);

    var errors = req.validationErrors();

    if(errors) {
    res.render('login.ejs', {errors: errors});
    } else {
        passport.authenticate('local-login', {
            successRedirect : '/list', // redirect to the secure list section
            failureRedirect : '/', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
            failureFlash : true // allow flash messages
        })(req, res, next);
    }
});
```

// Functions ================================================

```
function ifLoggedIn(req, res, next) {

// if user is authenticated in the session, carry on 
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return next();
    }
  console.log("cannot found in session");
  res.redirect('/');

}

function ifLoggedOut(req, res, next){
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        res.redirect('/list');
    }
    return next();
}


app.use('/', router);
}
```

// Error Log of Heroku

> 2015-08-20T07:37:07.490091+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
>   2015-08-20T07:37:07.490096+00:00 app[web.1]:     at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:335:11)
>   2015-08-20T07:37:07.490098+00:00 app[web.1]:     at ServerResponse.header (/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:718:10)
>   2015-08-20T07:37:07.490099+00:00 app[web.1]:     at ServerResponse.send (/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:163:12)
>   2015-08-20T07:37:07.490101+00:00 app[web.1]:     at done (/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:957:10)
>   2015-08-20T07:37:07.490103+00:00 app[web.1]:     at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/app/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:355:10)
>   2015-08-20T07:37:07.490105+00:00 app[web.1]:     at View.render (/app/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:126:8)
>   2015-08-20T07:37:07.490106+00:00 app[web.1]:     at tryRender (/app/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:639:10)
>   2015-08-20T07:37:07.490108+00:00 app[web.1]:     at EventEmitter.render (/app/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:591:3)
>   2015-08-20T07:37:07.490109+00:00 app[web.1]:     at ServerResponse.render (/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:961:7)
>   2015-08-20T07:37:07.490111+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/routes/routes.js:7:7
>   2015-08-20T07:37:07.490112+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
>   2015-08-20T07:37:07.490114+00:00 app[web.1]:     at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
>   2015-08-20T07:37:07.490115+00:00 app[web.1]:     at ifLoggedOut (/app/routes/routes.js:181:10)
>   2015-08-20T07:37:07.490117+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
>   2015-08-20T07:37:07.490118+00:00 app[web.1]:     at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
>   2015-08-20T07:37:07.490119+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Route.dispatch (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)

Comment: Could you please explain where do you get error exactly i mean at what part to what you try to do?

Comment: Hello, please describe your issue in detail. SO is not a dumping ground for your buggy code. (Also, the error tells you exactly what's wrong - your application tries to send header after it has been already sent -> rendering should be only called once in a request-response cycle)

Comment: @viddesh, here i added the error log and improved my question. sorry for not doing so from the beginning. i have found the error in the ifLoggedIn() and ifLoggedOut() but i'm not able to fully comprehend the reason behind the error.

Comment: @lazlojuly, yea i think this is the issue. would redirect() and next() affect each other? can you please check the IfLoggedIn function and help me understand the cause of the issue

Comment: I see that you have figured out the issue by yourself so I have improved on your answer instead of answering this myself.

Answer (score 2):

This issue was in the `ifLoggedIn` and `ifLoggedOut` functions where `next()` callback was called followed by the `redirect()` making two subsequent rendering calls. By using `return` with the `next()` callbacks these mistakes can be avoided.

original code:

```
function ifLoggedOut(req, res, next){
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        res.redirect('/list');
    }
    return next();
}
```

fixed version:

```
    function ifLoggedOut(req, res, next){
        if(req.isAuthenticated()){
            return res.redirect('/list');
        } 
        return next();
    }
```

Alternatively `if else` could have been used properly (without the need of `return`):

```
if(req.isAuthenticated()){
    res.redirect('/list');
} else {
    next();
}
```

Still, using `return` is a good practice to avoid mistakes like these.